# In pytorch, why does sum(tensor) return a fault result instead of torch.sum(tensor) sometimes?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I'm debugging , I meet a strange problem.

```py
>>> cos
>>>
tensor([ 0.3869,  0.2857,  0.4931,  0.5086,  0.6757,  0.6417,  0.3773,  0.4084,
         0.2496,  0.7558,  0.4305,  0.3839,  0.1892,  0.8675,  0.3392,  0.5415,
         0.4421,  0.2782,  0.5187,  0.2672,  0.2896,  0.5031,  0.4791,  0.3528,
         0.2577,  0.3932,  0.2554,  0.4925,  0.8496,  0.1264,  0.5594,  0.8667,
         ···
         0.4919,  0.4073,  0.6890,  0.3976,  0.5691,  0.0741,  0.6420,  0.4249,
         0.2785])
```

I want to calculate how many element is greater than zero, so I try this:

```py
>>> sum(cos>0)
>>> tensor(181, dtype=torch.uint8)  # fault answer
>>> torch.sum(cos>0)
>>> tensor(437)                     # correct answer
```

I also repeat the above operations, but the both answers turn to be right.

```py
>>> sum(cos[:100]>0)
>>> tensor(100, dtype=torch.uint8)
>>> torch.sum(cos[:100]>0)
>>> tensor(100)
```

I run this in pytorch 1.0.2 .

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Otherwise half the questions you see on StackOverflow will be "Why does X return a strange result."

Comment: Maybe a bug. I reproduced this in pytorch0.4.1 but in 0.3.0 I get a same result with the two statements. You can try to raise an issue at Github PyTorch project page.